# smaller distance between label and input element

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I have got a html form, designed with bootstrap classes. I would like to reduce the distance between the `<label>` (more pricesly the text) and the `<input>` element, as they are aranged horizontally at a breakpoint smaller than `sm` (576px).

[image: currently it looks like this]

The distance between "Anzahl" and the numeric input should be smaller.

This is my current code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-lg-center">         
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <label for="numAmount" class="form-label">Anzahl</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numAmount" required>
        </div>      
    </div>
    
    <div class="row justify-content-lg-center">         
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <label for"datDate" class="form-label">Datum</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 ">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datDate" value="<? echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" required>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use in the `label` the class `mb-0` that means `margin-bottom: 0px;` in your labels like this:

```
<div class="row justify-content-lg-center">         
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <label for="numAmount" class="form-label mb-0">Anzahl</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numAmount" required>
        </div>      
    </div>
    
    <div class="row justify-content-lg-center">         
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <label for"datDate" class="form-label mb-0">Datum</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 ">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datDate" value="<? echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" required>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Also, you can use this class with different numbers 1-5 to specify any margin-bottom as you needed, see also this about the other helper classes like this:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/

Answer (score 1):

just zero out margin-bottom on the form-label class

```css
.form-label{
margin-bottom:0!important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row justify-content-lg-center">         
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <label for="numAmount" class="form-label">Anzahl</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="numAmount" required>
        </div>      
    </div>
    
    <div class="row justify-content-lg-center">         
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 d-flex justify-content-md-end">
            <label for"datDate" class="form-label">Datum</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-3 ">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datDate" value='<? echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>' required>
        </div>      
    </div>
```